# Newer version of libc6-dev package causes havoc

Tags: linux, debian, gcc, mips

I have a `mips64` machine running `Debian` `Wheezy`. `GCC` compiler installs without any issues, however, linker is having some trouble:

```
apt-get install gcc make
gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
```

A quick internet search shows that I am allegedly missing `libc6-dev`, however, it is the wrong version:

```
apt-get install libc6-dev
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-38+deb7u9) but 2.13-38+deb7u10 is to be installed
```

Forcing the install with:

```
apt-get download libc6-dev
dpkg -i --force-all libc6-dev_2.13-38+deb7u9_mips.deb
```

Fixes the problem, but now every time that I use `apt` tools, they complain that I have incompatible packages. I tried the following:

```
apt-get install libc6-dev=2.13-38+deb7u9
libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-38+deb7u9) but 2.13-38+deb7u10 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Also, trying to upgrade the "parent" package `lib6`, says I already have the latest version (which is 2.13-38+deb7u9).

This problem appeared two days ago (probably when `libc6-dev` 2.13-38+deb7u10 was released, but without the same version of `libc6`). Is there a way to satisfy all the dependencies here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem, the package repository did not have the latest `libc-dev-bin` for some reason, so the following fixes the problem:

```
curl -O http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc-dev-bin_2.13-38+deb7u10_mips.deb
dpkg -i libc-dev-bin_2.13-38+deb7u10_mips.deb
apt-get install gcc make automake autoconf linux-libc-dev
curl -O http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-dev_2.13-38+deb7u10_mips.deb
dpkg -i libc6-dev_2.13-38+deb7u10_mips.deb
```

(it needs to be in that order) When I changed the repositories in the sources.list, the problem is still there, so I guess the cause will be fixed at some point.

Answer (score -1):

My system had libc6-deb7u11 installed, so I had to replace it with u10. Package is at:

http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6_2.13-38+deb7u10_mips.deb

Comment: The existing answer already indicates that